# Install .NET core 2.0.0 on Manjaro for Rider IDE

Tags: .net-core, rider, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro and I would like to use Rider instead of Visual Studio on Windows for my .Net class. Using pamac I found sdk and runtime for the version 2.1. However, I need the 2.0.0 version. I try to install it from binaries but Rider don't find it. The only one he found is 2.1 does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: 2.0 was end of life'd a few months ago. It will not receive any security fixes or other bugfixes. Are you sure you really want to use it?

Comment: Yeah, that's a teacher request. (Notably to use AccountController) which is modified in 2.1 by razorfile (?).

Comment: “I try to install it from binaries”? Why? There is a installs script so that you can easily install .NET Core 2.0 runtime, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SideBySideUserScopedNETCoreInstallationsOnLinuxWithDotnetinstallsh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. In Rider, go to *File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build*.
2. Modify values of two settings, *.NET Core CLI executable path* and *Use MSBuild version*, to point to your custom installation.